# Why do int lterals go on heap when they are referenced?

Tags: rust

When I run

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", &0);
    println!("{:p}", &1);
}
```

in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e77015f9dbf35dca12731be50f385700)
I get something like

```
0x560882842004
0x560882842008
```

implying that `0` and `1` were placed on the heap. Why?

Comment: How is this implying they go on the heap? They most definitely don't – they are either on the stack or in the static data segment.

Comment: If you are taking a reference to a value, it would logically follow that the value has to be stored somewhere, in this case - in the .data segment of the executable.

Comment: Basically, that a value has an address doesn't mean that it's on the heap.

Comment: Fair enough. I was assuming that since the values are much lower than stack ones I've observed, it bust be on the heap. Thanks for pointing out this incorrect assumption and that the values lie in the static data segment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not placed on the heap. They're in the static read-only data segment of the compiled binary and are loaded into read-only memory at run-time. Every hardcoded `&T` in Rust source code gets a `'static` lifetime for that reason. Example:

```rust
fn returns_static_immutable_readonly_num() -> &'static i32 {
    &0 // compiles
}
```

Comment: You can have [`&T`s without an owner that go on the stack](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=162919a81ec0bcf28adaa8c67a362602).

Comment: I wouldn't say the `&T` in that example doesn't have an owner, but rather that it has an anonymous owner that is dropped at the end of the current scope (along with the reference itself) so the compiler allows it. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc9c30b34fe8a473a05c3b0c1b6a3f7a).

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow where the "anonymous owner" comes from. For what it's worth, here's the [reference for lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension).